# How do you account for xml nodes with no children?

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Right now I am running into some issues with some XML I am walking through with jQuery.

The nodes have 2 styles to them:

```
<stylegroup></stylegroup>
<stylegroup/>
```

So right now I was just iterating over the nodes and saying:

```
data.children().each(function(){
     console.log("node", $(this).prop("nodeName"));
     console.log("value", $(this).text());
});
```

As you can guess, it would work for the upper example, but not the one without children of sorts.

How would i account for this?   Check to see if it has children before getting the text?

When I call `$(this).text()` on the `<stylegroup/>` it will actually print out **everything** after it, looking for an end tag.

Edit:   http://jsfiddle.net/sLMxk/

Comment: Can you set a jsfiddle?!

Comment: its a simple fiddle, too simple i thought i wouldnt need one, but here you go.

Comment: But problem is not with XML but with the XML beeing parsed to HTML by browser. Don't add XML to the DOM   http://jsfiddle.net/sLMxk/1/

Comment: So, in this case, i should do something like:  get the data from the body, and then run it through `$.parseXML();` ?

Comment: I do see what you are saying though. :) Thank you.

Comment: In the case of JSFiddle, i wanted to use the HTML content block as the space to build my XML example. How would i approach it in that case? Scrape thebody content nodes etc and then run it through parseXML?

Comment: XML != HTML : the two are incompatible. If you want something to behave like XML, use an XML parser to build the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is read differently in the markup of DOM, in a way that XML is not doing.